# Replace movieclip palced manualy in timeline with movieclip from library

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem that after a lot of searches I didn't manage to solve it.

I created 2 movie clips in the library (let say `mc1` and `mc2`). Then I manually create another movie clip in timeline (using IDE), let say `foo`.

As background inside `foo` I use `mc1` with instance name `bg`. In ActionScript I'm trying to replace the `foo.bg` with `mc2`.

Please note that I already exported `mc1` and `mc2` to first frame with classes `mc1()` and `mc2()`.

**I tried** (without any luck) :

```
var mc1:movieClip = new mc1()
var mc2:movieClip = new mc2()

if (....)
{
foo.bg=mc2;

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Mistake №1: managing objects in display list is not the same thing as assigning variables.
Mistake №2: variable names and class name **MUST** be different. On a case-level, at least.

So, you need to do something like that:

```
var mc1:MovieClip = new MC1;
var mc2:MovieClip = new MC2;

// ...

// Delete existing background.
foo.removeChild(foo.bg);

// Set the new background.
foo.addChild(mc2);
foo.bg = mc2;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I will try that.